# Load test throwing exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I have a visual studio 2015 load test project , that run serveral integration test

When I run the integration test stand alone they pass

When I run them via load test I get an exception :

> Unit Test Adapter threw exception: The constructor to deserialize an
>   object of type 'Hosting.Service.HostingRuntimeException' was not
>   found..

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909195/unit-test-adapter-threw-exception-unable-to-load-one-or-more-of-the-requested-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424162/serializationexceptions-in-unittests) but the solution there do not work

Comment: I had a similar problem, but I cannot remember what I did to resolve the problem. Could you describe your situation more specifically? It may ring a bell for me or for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Enable deployment was not checked .

In the Local.testsettings go Deployment tab and click the check the deployment chec box

[image]to the